# How to correctly add a bible reference in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am working on a book re-edition, in which I have already found two biblical quotations, so I have had to add it to the list of references.

I'm using `biblatex` for that and I am curious to know how I would have to quote some biblical passage. For example, if I have to quote Leviticus, chapter 16, verse 22, I don't know how to do it correctly.

I have searched here for related questions to the bible in hopes of finding the solution to my problem, but what I have found has been something related to how to compose the bible rather than to quote it.

A kindsort of MWE would be:

```
@Book{Bible2009,
  title      = {La Bible},
  date       = {2009},
  editor     = {Gilbert, Pierre and Römer, Thomas},
  translator = {Echenoz, Jean and Carrère, Emmanuel and NDiaye, Marie and Bon, François and Roubard, Jacques and Cadiot, Olivier and Depussé, Marie and Novarina, Valère},
  titleaddon = {nouvelle traduction},
  series     = {Domaine biblique},
  publisher  = {Bayard},
  isbn       = {978-2227479098},
  pagetotal  = {2512},
  url        = {http://www.bayard-editions.com/religions-et-sciences-humaines/religions/domaine-biblique/la-bible-nouvelle-traduction},
  urldate    = {2017-06-16}
}
```

I want to use the `crossref` field for citing the Bible's books without rewriting all the data. At first I thought about the `bookinbook` entry type, but I don't know how to cite the verse, so from the example above I was doing something like this:

```
@BookInBook{Lv2009,
  title     = {Levitique},
  booktitle = {La Bible},
  year      = {2009},
  chapter   = {16}
}
```

Would anyone have experience or any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14126/good-latex-package-for-typesetting-bible-quotations) and [this reference](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bibleref/bibleref.pdf) about the `bibleref` package.  I hope it helps!

Comment: depends on the citation style you're using. if you're for example using APA style, you'd go: `(John; 3:16, New International Version)`

Comment: Oh, and here's a reference for [how to properly cite the Bible](http://www.wikihow.com/Cite-the-Bible) within your text.

Comment: @naphaneal I know about it, but I don't use APA, the author use the `footnotecite` style, so APA doesn't matters.

Comment: Not an answer: Citing the Bible, in general: https://www.messiah.edu/murraylibrary/guides/bible_cite.pdf

Comment: @sk8forether Wow, Nicola Talbot has great packages like this one I didn't know.

Comment: @sk8forether Thanks, I read it before ask my question, but I think my problem is quite different.

Comment: Since the Bible is a primary source, I would put the reference in parentheses after the quote even if you are using a footnote style. Exactly how you format the reference and what (if anything) you put in the bibliography depends on your citation style.

Comment: @DavidPurton I'm indeed and I'm using a footnote citation style following the author's way of make citations, in this case the citation is `Lévitique, XVI 22, dans F. Boyer (dir.), La Bible: nouvelle traduction, Bayard, 2009.`

Comment: @Aradnix, this is a pretty weird way to reference a Bible verse. But if you're copying what someone else has done, maybe can you expand your question with a full [MWE with bibliography](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) and the output that you'd like in both the footnote and the bibliography.